# Número máximo y mínimo en un contador C

Tags: c

tengo una función de C que actúa como un "contador" en la que tu introduces 7 números diferentes (Uno por día de la semana) y te dice cual ha sido el máximo y el mínimo ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me diga en que día fue cuando se introdujo el máximo y el mínimo (Referido como Lunes a 1, martes a 2...)

```
int main()
{
printf("¿Cuantos pasos ha dado?\n");
    scanf("%f",&PasosDados);
    CaloriasQuemadas = kilocalorias(PasosDados);
}

int datos_semana(){
float media;
float metrosrecorridos;
int num=0,max=0,min=0,contador=0,suma=0;

printf ("Introduce los números de pasos de esta semana");
scanf ("%d",&num);
max=num;
min=num;
suma=num;
while (contador<6){
        scanf ("%d",&num);
        if (num>max){
            max=num;
        }else if (num<min){
            min=num;
        }
        suma+=num;//suma=suma+num;  
        contador++;
}
media=suma/(float)7;
metrosrecorridos=globalpaso*suma*0.01;
printf ("La media es %f\n",media);
printf ("En esta semana has recorrido %f metros\n",metrosrecorridos);
printf ("El maximo es %d y el minimo es %d \n",max,min);
return(suma);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución: en lugar de almacenar los valores máximo y mínimo en si, creas una formación que contenga los valores de cada día, y almacenas **el índice** a esa formación:

```
float datos_semana( ) {
  const char *nombreDias[] = {
    "Lunes",
    "Martes",
    "Miercoles",
    "Jueves",
    "Viernes",
    "Sabado",
    "Domingo"
  };

  float pasosPorDias[7];
  float suma = 0.0f;
  float max = 0.0f, min = -1.0f;
  int idxMin = 0, idxMax = 0;

  printf ( "Introduce los números de pasos de esta semana\n" );

  for( int idx = 0; idx < 7; ++idx ) {
    float pasos;
    printf( "Pasos del %s: ", nombreDias[idx] );
    scanf ("%f", &pasos );

    pasosPorDias[idx] = pasos;

    if( pasos > max ) { idxMax = idx; max = pasos; }
    if( ( min < 0 ) || ( pasos < min ) ) { idxMin = idx; min = pasos; }

    suma += pasos;
  }

  printf ( "La media es %f\n", suma / 7 );
  printf ( "En esta semana has recorrido %f metros\n", globalpaso * suma * 0.01f );
  printf ("El maximo fue el %s: %f pasos\n", nombreDias[idxMax], pasosPorDias[idxMax] );
  printf ("El minimo fue el %s: %f pasos\n", nombreDias[idxMin], pasosPorDias[idxMin] );

  return suma;
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: Te he arreglado un poco el código, que estaba *echo unos zorros* :-)</sub>

Comment: Me compila bien, pero me pone que el máximo y el mínimo es siempre el domingo y no se que puede estar mal

Comment: Un momento, lo miro. Me pasa por no probar las coas :-(

Comment: Sin problema :)

Comment: @Edurex Ya, listo. Fallo tonto en los `if( )`. *I'm sorry* :-(

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias